# Listar diretório específicos no Windows - Filtro na listagem

Tags: windows, cmd

Tenho o cenário com os seguinte diretórios em ordem alfabética:

```
Y:\imagens\A001\B001\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A001\B002\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A002\B001\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A002\B002\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A003\B001\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A003\B002\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A004\B001\imagem.jpg
Y:\imagens\A004\B002\imagem.jpg
```

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando para listar todos os arquivos recursivamente e jogando a saída em um arquivo:

```
dir "Y:\imagens" /a-d /b /s > arquivo_de_saida.txt
```

Acontece que meu comando parou de listar os arquivos quando estava quase no final e não quero começar tudo de novo, pois são milhões de arquivos.

Quero listar apenas os diretórios depois de "A002".

Comment: sem pesquisar se realmente há uma solução pra isso... renomeia A001 e A002 para xA001 e xA002, e roda `dir "Y:\imagens\A*" /a-d /b /s > arquivo_de_saida2.txt`

Comment: Obrigado @RovannLinhalis ... Porém assim ainda fica inviável pra mim pois são 5000 diretórios porém faltam 2000.

Comment: A002 incluindo ou apenas começando a partir de A003...?

Comment: Nossa, só agora eu vi que a pergunta foi feita a quase 4 anos atrás...

Answer (score 0):

Para listar todos os que são **.jpg** de forma recursiva e depois da pasta **`Y:\imagens\A002`** você pode tentar usar o **`where`** dentro de um loop **`for`** filtrada por **`find`** evitando a pasta **A002** de listar, e pegando com **`findstr`** usando **regex** nas pastas desejadas:

---

```bat
:: via linha de comando ::
   cd /d "Y:\imagens" && where /r . "*.jpg" | findstr /vc:"\A002" | findstr /r \A[0-9] 

:: via arquivo bat/cmd ::
   @echo off & cd /d "Y:\imagens" && where /r . "*.jpg" | findstr /vc:"\A002" | findstr /r \A[0-9]

:: usando um loop for na linha de comando ::
   @cd /d "Y:\imagens" && for /f ^tokens^=* %i in ('where /r . "*.jpg" ^| findstr /vc:"\A002" ^| findstr /r \A[0-9]')do @echo/%i

:: usando um loop For no bat/cmd ::
   @echo cd /d "Y:\imagens" && for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r . "*.jpg" ^| findstr /vc:"\A002" ^| findstr /r \A[0-9]')do echo/%%i
```

---

> - **Salvar** saída num **arquivo.log** **`"%temp%\saida_salva.log"`**

```bat
:: via linha de comando ::
   @cd /d Y:\imagens && where /r . "*.jpg" | findstr /vc:"\A002" | findstr /r \A[0-9] >"%temp%\saida_salva.log" <nul

:: via arquivo bat/cmd ::
   @echo off & cd /d "Y:\imagens" && where /r . "*.jpg" | findstr /vc:"\A002" | findstr /r \A[0-9] >"%temp%\saida_salva.log" <nul

:: usando um loop For no bat/cmd ::
   @echo off & cd /d "Y:\imagens" && for /f ^tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r . "*.jpg" ^| findstr /vc:"\A002" ^| findstr /r \A[0-9]')do echo/%%i >"%temp%\saida_salva.log" <nul

:: usando um loop for na linha de comando ::
   @cd /d "Y:\imagens" && for /f ^tokens^=* %i in ('where /r . "*.jpg" ^| findstr /vc:"\A002" ^| findstr /r \A[0-9]')do @echo/%~i >"%temp%\saida_salva.log" <nul
```

Comment: Eu testei a versão "via arquivo bat/cmd ::" e no meu caso ela só ocultou a pasta A002 e não "todas as pastas anteriores"....por exemplo A001 apareceu normal.

Comment: @RicardoBohner Eita! Então tem adicionar mais um `^| findstr /vc:"\A001"`... vou editar em casa.. Valew

Comment: Mais e se fosse para só listar a partir de A027 ou algo assim tem que fazer isso para cada pasta?

Comment: @RicardoBohner Agora que caiu a ficha! Q cosa nô!?

Comment: @RicardoBohner Aí seria listar as pastas/caminhos excluindo os itens que já estão no arquivo usando o findstr /v items_no_arquivo.txt

Comment: Caramba, não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade. Só listar os arquivos que não existem na listagem que ficou pela metade...mais será que esse processo todo não vai levar mais tempo do que criar um arquivo do zero mesmo que tenha milhões de arquivos?

Comment: @RicardoBohner só testando que se vai saber se leva maior, menor ou o mesmo tempo...